# Finding the (usob)Hash of a Core Data /OData Service Required for the Authorization Object S_SERVICE (parameter SRV_NAME)

Tags: sap-basis, cds

To access an OData web service that exposes data from a Core Data Service (CDS) in SAP R/3, a user needs has to have an authorization role assigned that contains the authorization object `S_SERVICE`.

The authorization object `S_SERVICE` requires two parameters:

1. the **service type** (`SRV_TYPE`) which is set to `HT` = "TADIR Object" in my case
2. the **service hash** (`SRV_NAME`).

Using the debugger I found out, that the function module `AUTHORITY_CHECK_TADIR_SERVICE` compares the hash from the `S_SERVICE` authorization object with the hash stored in a record of table `usobhash`:
[image: se16 view of table usobhash]

I also found out, that function module `AUTH_TRACE_CALC_HASH` uses the data from the columns `PGMID`, `OBJECT` and `OBJ_NAME` in table `usobhash` as input to generate the hash which is then stored in column `NAME`.

So far, whenever I wanted to grant a user/role permission to access a OData service I needed to know this hash. To get the hash, I either checked the usobhash table or manually executed `AUTH_TRACE_CALC_HASH` and then entered the hash when I assigned the authorization object to an authorization role in transaction `pfcg`. I guess there has to be an easier, more "official" way to do this. My approach feels like a dirty workaround but I was unable to find any documentation about how to do it right.

**tl;dr** How do I set the `S_SERVICE` authorization object without either debugging `AUTH_TRACE_CALC_HASH` or searching for the relevant entry in `usobhash`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a role with the Service in it. Therefore please create a new or choose an existing role in the transaction `PFCG` → (+ pushbutton).
2. Choose the object type "Authorization Default".
   [image: in transaction pfcg choose "authorization default]
3. Choose "TADIR Service"; Choose object type `IWSV` or `IWSG`.
4. Use the F4 help to select your service.
   [image: in the service dialogue use F4 help to find your service]
5. Save the role.
6. Assign the role to user.